# I would like to perform some arithmetic operation based on the selection of a radio/checkbox button. How to code the action listener on this button?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to take values from radio and checkbox button based on selection. After that perform addition of given values and show them in textbox. I'm confused between ActionListener and itemlistner

```
import java.awt.; 
import java.awt.event.; 
import javax.swing.*; 
 class roomcost implements ActionListener {
  Button b1;
  TextField t1;
  Label l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7;
  JFrame f;
  JCheckBox c1,c2,c3;
  JRadioButton r1,r2;
  ButtonGroup bg;
  roomcost() {
   JFrame f = new JFrame("Hotel Room Reservation");

    Label l1 = new Label("Room Type:");
    Label l2 = new Label("Facilities:");
    Label l3 = new Label("cost:");
    Label l4 = new Label(" ");
    Label l5 = new Label(" ");
    Label l6 = new Label(" ");
    Label l7 = new Label(" ");
    t1 = new TextField();
    c1 = new JCheckBox("Breakfast");
    c2 = new JCheckBox("Lunch");
    c3 = new JCheckBox("Dinner");
    r1 = new JRadioButton("AC");
    r2 = new JRadioButton("Non-AC");
    ButtonGroup group=new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(r1);
    group.add(r2);
    r1.setSelected(true);
    r1.addActionListener(this);
    r2.addActionListener(this);
    b1 = new Button("Calculate");
    b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2,3));
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    f.add(l1);f.add(r1);f.add(r2);f.add(l4);
    f.add(l2);f.add(c1);f.add(c2);f.add(c3);
    f.add(l3);f.add(t1);f.add(l5);f.add(l6);
    f.add(l7);f.add(b1);
    f.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4,20,30));
    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
       
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    }



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 


 }



public static void main(String args[]) {
    roomcost rc = new roomcost();
}
```

}

Because of grid layout I tried to empty labels for layout managing, [image]would love to know if there's a better way to do it ,I've attached output of awt(GUI).

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is to create a calculateCost() that then checks if the radio/check boxes are selected to alter the value.  Then have your listener call that method.  For example:

```
public void calculateAndDiplay() {
      float cost = 15.00;
      if (r2.isSelected()) {
         cost += 20;
      }
      if (c1.isSelected()) {
        cost += 5;
      }
      if (c2.isSelected()) {
        cost += 8;
      }
      if (c3.isSelected()) {
        cost += 10;
      }
      t1.setText(Float.toString(cost));
}
```